# How to instantiate Dynamoose Model from DynamoDB's AttributeValue format?

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk, dynamoose

I am using Dynamodb streams to do some work on records as they are added or modified to my table. I am also using Dynamoose models in my application.

The Dynamodb stream event passes an event object to my node.js lambda handler that includes the objects `record.dynamoDb.NewImage` and `record.dynamoDb.OldImage`. However, these objects are in DynamoDB's AttributeValue format including all of the data types ('S' for string), rather than a normal javascript object. So `record.id` becomes `record.id.S`.

Dynamoose models allow you to instantiate a model from an object, like so: `new Model(object)`. However, it expects that argument to be a normal object.

I know that Dynamoose has a dynamodb parser, I think its Schema.prototype.dynamodbparse(). However, that doesn't work as expected.

```
import { DYNAMODB_EVENT } from '../../constant';
import _get from 'lodash/get';
import { Entry } from '../../model/entry';
import { applyEntry } from './applyEntry';

async function entryStream(event) {
  await Promise.all(
    event.Records.map(async record => {
      // If this record is being deleted, do nothing
      if (DYNAMODB_EVENT.Remove === record.eventName) {
        return;
      }

      // What I've tried:
      let entry = new Entry(record.dynamodb.NewImage);

      // What I wish I could do
      entry = new Entry(Entry.schema.dynamodbparse(record.dynamodb.newImage));
      await applyEntry(entry);
    })
  );
}

export const handler = entryStream;
```

So is there a way to instantiate a Dynamoose model from DynamoDB's AttributeValue format? Has anyone else done this?

The alternative, is that I simply extract the key from the `record`, and then make a trip to the database using `Model.get({ id: idFromEvent });` But I think that would be inefficient, since the record was just handed to me from the stream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using `AWS.DynamoDB.Converter.unmarshall` to parse the object before passing to Dynamoose.

```
import { DYNAMODB_EVENT } from '../../constant';
import _get from 'lodash/get';
import { Entry } from '../../model/entry';
import { applyEntry } from './applyEntry';

// https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/Converter.html#unmarshall-property
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var parseDynamo = AWS.DynamoDB.Converter.unmarshall;

async function entryStream(event) {
  await Promise.all(
    event.Records.map(async record => {
      // If this record is being deleted, do nothing
      if (DYNAMODB_EVENT.Remove === record.eventName) {
        return;
      }

      entry = new Entry(parseDynamo(record.dynamodb.newImage));
      await applyEntry(entry);
    })
  );
}

export const handler = entryStream;
```